# Center zooming (width/height/top/left) smoothly

Tags: jquery, events

So, I'm converting a flash widget into HTML/CSS/JS and I'm having problems emulating a center-oriented zooming effect for images.

So, currently I have a structure in HTML like this:

```
<div id="outer">
  <img />
</div>
```

With CSS similar to the following:

```
#outer{
  width: 690px;
  height: 440px;
  position: relative;
}
#outer img{
  width: 690px;
  height: 440px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Then in jQuery, I'm doing this to create the zoom effect:

```
$image = $("#outer img");
scale = 1.16;
var w = parseInt($image.data("width")); //Set earlier to 690px
var h = parseInt($image.data("height")); //Set earlier to 440px
$image
  .animate({
    width: w*scale,
    height: h*scale,
    left: -(((w*scale) - w)/2),
    top: -(((h*scale) - h)/2)
  }, 5000, "linear");
```

[jFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DusRy/1/)

It's a little hard to see with this specific image that I found but it's (for one reason or another) more easily seen in the images my client gave me. What I'm seeing is a jagged/shaky/jittery movement which I assume might be because decimal values for left/top/width/height not lining up well enough to keep it centered always.

Is there a better way to go about this or maybe an easing function that will produce a better result?

If there's anything I can clear up, let me know.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've begun to think maybe if I could write an easing function that would increase the width/height by 2 every time the left/top decreases by 1 to make it stay center all the time, but I'm not sure how to go about that in jQuery. I tried messing around with the `step` argument of the `animate` function but I can't figure out how to force the left/top properties to increase/decrease by integer values (whole numbers) only...

Answer (score 6):

You can always try CSS3 animations, but there's a huge problem with it, IE9 doesn't support it...

However it's pretty smooth, check the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/YSJQu/

```
#outer img {
    (...)
    animation:zoom 5s;
    -moz-animation:zoom 5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:zoom 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:zoom 5s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from { transform:scale(1) }
    to { transform:scale(1.2) }
}
@-moz-keyframes zoom {
    from { -moz-transform:scale(1) }
    to { -moz-transform:scale(1.2) }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from { -webkit-transform:scale(1) }
    to { -webkit-transform:scale(1.2) }
}
@-o-keyframes zoom {
    from { -o-transform:scale(1) }
    to { -o-transform:scale(1.2) }
}
```

Comment: That works beatufily but my client needs IE6(!) support. I'll just have to tell him that these kinds of side effects are one of the very few disadvantages of switching away from flash. Thanks though.

Comment: And, sorry, but I'm a huge 24 fan and you have the same name (spelled differently) as one of the main characters (http://24.wikia.com/wiki/Tony_Almeida). I had to point that out, haha.

Comment: **+1** Great answer. Here is another demo using CSS3 transform scale: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/btZUQ/1)

Comment: Yeah I've heard about him, I'm Toni Almeida longer than him :) 
By the way, in Portugal we didn't have Y in our dictionary until 2011, so we read Tony the same way as Toni...
Despite not having watched the series, i'm still proud to have the same name as an American character lol.
Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Animations had been hard subject in HTML. Some solutions work smoothly in desktops, but not so smooth in mobiles and vice-versa, across browsers they usually performs differently too.

If you are coming from a Flash background, I could easily recommend [GSAP JS](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/). It will perform *a lot* better than jQuery. Its javascript based, and have almost identical syntaxes for both JS and AS.

They also provide a good  [speed test](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html). Maybe you would like to try.

Comment: That library is pretty awesome and I expected fantastic performance based on your demo but when I implemented it, it actually began shaking much worse. :/

Comment: I've seen some discussion around CSS transforms performing way better than absolute positioning / image resizing. Maybe you could try [Scale CSS Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for the same effect. I think CSS transforms take advantage from the hardware acceleration. Maybe it'll solve your issue.

Comment: Using scale and transform still caused about the same amount of jitter as absolute positioning. If I didn't need to support IE I would just go with CSS3 animations like @Toni said below but whatever. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pRup7/) 2nd Example

A great jQuery library to handle zoom requirements is [**.transit() plugin**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).

```js
$(".thumbnail-1").hover(
    function () {
     $(this).stop(true,true).transition({ scale: 1.3 });
  }, 
    function () {
    $(this).stop(true,true).transition({ scale: 1.0 });
  }
);
```